# Add joining lines between flex items in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am creating a "tree" in bootstrap 5, this is to be a list of items that something can be followed down into, for this I am using bootstrap 5 and raw HTML

I have the HTML set up for this, as per below;

[image]

However I would like to have lines between these as per the following image;

[image]

I have tried creating some custom CSS for this, but no matter what I have done, this has got me stumped, nor can I find anything about this on the bootstrap documentation

The HTML powering this is as follows;

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: check this it might help you https://codepen.io/Pestov/pen/AvQmxv

Comment: Hm, that doesn't join child-child, will try and mess about and see what I can cook up (which sounds weird, but it's a skill-tree, so less weird)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an upper border for your levels, except for the first and then instead of your brs, create a div which is divided to the number of parents and each division divided into two, with borders between them. This is almost what you wanted, we can further enhance this solution by adding a "before" level as well, but I think this is already a good proof-of-concept.

```css
.newline {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}

.pc-50 {
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
    width: 50%;
}

.newline:not(.lower) > div div:not(.outsider) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

.pc-33 {
    width: 33.33%;
}

.pc-20 {
    width: 20%;
}

.pc-50.left {
    border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around first">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex newline">
    <div class="d-flex pc-50 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left outsider"></div>
        <div class="pc-50 left"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-50">
        <div class="pc-50 left"></div>
        <div class="pc-50 left outsider"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex newline lower">
    <div class="d-flex pc-50 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left outsider"></div>
        <div class="pc-50"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-50 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left"></div>
        <div class="pc-50 outsider"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex newline">
    <div class="d-flex pc-50 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left outsider d-flex">
            <div class="pc-50 left outsider"></div>
            <div class="pc-50 left"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-50 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 outsider d-flex">
            <div class="pc-50 left"></div>
            <div class="pc-50 left outsider"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex newline lower">
    <div class="d-flex pc-50 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left outsider d-flex">
            <div class="pc-50 left outsider"></div>
            <div class="pc-50"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-50">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 outsider d-flex left">
            <div class="pc-50 left"></div>
            <div class="pc-50 outsider"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex newline">
    <div class="d-flex pc-33 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left outsider d-flex">
            <div class="pc-50 left outsider"></div>
            <div class="pc-50 left"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-33 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-33 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 outsider d-flex">
            <div class="pc-50 left"></div>
            <div class="pc-50 left outsider"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex newline lower">
    <div class="d-flex pc-33 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left outsider d-flex">
            <div class="pc-50 left outsider"></div>
            <div class="pc-50"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-33 left">
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-33 left">
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 outsider d-flex left">
            <div class="pc-50 left"></div>
            <div class="pc-50 outsider"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex newline">
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left outsider">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 outsider">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex newline lower">
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50  outsider left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 outsider left     ">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex newline">
    <div class="d-flex pc-50 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left outsider d-flex">
            <div class="pc-50 left outsider"></div>
            <div class="pc-50 left"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-50 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 outsider d-flex">
            <div class="pc-50 left"></div>
            <div class="pc-50 left outsider"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex newline lower">
    <div class="d-flex pc-50 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left outsider d-flex">
            <div class="pc-50 left outsider"></div>
            <div class="pc-50"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-50 left">
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 outsider d-flex left        ">
            <div class="pc-50 left"></div>
            <div class="pc-50 outsider"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex newline">
    <div class="d-flex pc-33 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left outsider d-flex">
            <div class="pc-50 left outsider"></div>
            <div class="pc-50 left"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-33 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-33 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 outsider d-flex">
            <div class="pc-50 left"></div>
            <div class="pc-50 left outsider"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex newline lower">
    <div class="d-flex pc-33 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left outsider d-flex">
            <div class="pc-50 left outsider"></div>
            <div class="pc-50"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-33 left">
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-33 left">
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 outsider d-flex left">
            <div class="pc-50 left"></div>
            <div class="pc-50 outsider"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex newline">
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left outsider">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 outsider">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex newline lower">
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left ">
        <div class="pc-50 left outsider">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 ">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 left">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex pc-20 left">
        <div class="pc-50 ">
        </div>
        <div class="pc-50 left outsider">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight border border-primary">Flex item 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ooh, now this is intriguing... DO you know of any way to stop the lines going past the start of the first and last flex items on the row?

Comment: @CanO'Spam edited my answer to remove those edges. If you want the exact same thing as you had in the question, then you will need two levels of newline and a border bottom to the upper level and apply the same pattern (divide the screen to the number of items and divide each division into two). If this answer solved your problem then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: You're an absolute hero! I cannot thank you enough! CSS is far from my strong suit <3

Comment: @CanO'Spam I have edited the snippet in my answer to have nicer blue lines. Credit goes to my wife, who did the improvements, as I was too lazy to do them :)